# Error when trying to set a DWORD value in the windows registry using C #

Tags: c#, .net, registry, uint32, dword

I'm writing code that sets a value in the Windows registry. when I set that value manually, it works as expected; when I want to set the value programmatically, however, it gives an error. The value I want to define is a DWORD value type that is "4294967295". When I define that in the script, though, it says that DWORD does not support this value. And, yet, I can assign that exact value via the program I am using to manually update the registry.

Here's my code:

```cs
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Lost in Days Studio\NO TIME", true);
key.SetValue("Current", 4294967295, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.Close();
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I assume that by manually setting the value, you mean through e.g. `RegEdit.msc` or a similar application? Out of curiosity, what application are you using to manually edit your Windows Registry?

Comment: I go through regedit, and the program I'm editing is a game

Comment: When calling `RegistryKey.SetValue` with `RegistryValueKind.DWord`, the method tries to `Convert.ToInt32()` the Value you passed on. Use `QWord` instead. If you don't specify the Type and you set `uint.MaxValue`, it will store a string.

Comment: @Jimi: Shouldn’t it call `Convert.ToUInt32()` internally, since a `DWORD` is an unsigned integer? That said, if it did, I’d expect the OP’s code to work correctly since a `long` with the value of `uint.MaxValue` can obviously be converted to a `uint`.

Comment: @Jeremy Caney  [RegistryKey.SetValue()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs,1555) calls `Convert.ToInt32()`, `Int32` is not a `long`.

Comment: Issue #24954 - [Registry.GetValue returns an Int32 for REG_DWORD instead of an Uint32](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24954) (can't fix).

Answer (score 5):

As you likely know, a DWORD is [stored as a 32 bit binary number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryValueKind_DWord). What may not be immediately obvious, though, is that it's *unsigned*—and, thus, a `UInt32` (`uint`). Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to store a value of `4294967295`, since [the maximum value for a signed integer (`int`) is 2,147,483,647](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types).

There's a catch, however! As @Jimi noted in the comments, `SetValue()` will attempt to do a `Convert.ToInt32()`, which will cause an overflow with any value above `Int32.MaxValue`—thus the error you are receiving. One would *expect* it to use `Convert.ToUInt32()` but, as @Jimi *also* discovered, that is [a known bug in the method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24954), which Microsoft is unable to fix due to backward compatibility concerns.

*Instead*, the `SetValue()` method converts a signed `Int32` (`int`) into an unsigned 32 bit binary number, with values of `0…2147483647` remaining as is, but values of `-2147483647…-1` getting saved to the `2147483648…4294967295` range.

That binary conversion is a bit convoluted if you're thinking about this as a signed integer. But, fortunately, you can use [C#’s built-in `unchecked()` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) to permit the overflow and effectively treat your `uint` as a signed `int` within those ranges:

```cs
key.SetValue("Current", unchecked((int)4294967295), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

This is really handy because it allows for you to continue to work with a standard `UInt32` (`uint`) range of `0…4294967295`, exactly like you would via e.g. RegEdit, without having to think about how the binary conversion is being handled.